# Using VARCHAR or TEXT as default String mapping in OpenJPA

Tags: postgresql, jpa, openjpa

By default, OpenJPA's `postgres` dictionary generates `VARCHAR(255)` for `String` fields without stated length. Can it be set up to generate `VARCHAR` or `TEXT` instead for all such fields, so that I don't need to repeat `@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")` everywhere? Of course, if the length is given explicitly, e.g. `@Column(length = 128)`, the result should be `VARCHAR(128)`. For that matter, do any other JPA providers allow this?

Comment: @siebz0r Yes, the question says so.

Comment: Have you tried the `columnDefinition` parameter in the `@Column` annotation?

Comment: @siebz0r I want to get this behavior for _all_ `String` fields. I'll edit the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Hibernate supports this since 3.6: [6.5. Type Registry](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-registry). Tracked by this JIRA issue: [HHH-5138](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-5138).